# Show multiple address in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dynamic-programming

Is there no way (native) to show multiple addresses in a Google Maps map? I can't find that at the developer sites, and when I find something, it's just for static use, not for dynamic sites.

For example on airbnb.com there is such a "multiple dynamic address implementation" (if you search for a city).

Thanks in advance!
Best regards, john.

Comment: You can't or don't want to use the [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics)?

Comment: oh, thanks for the tip. i'm a little bit blind from the whole day of coding, but here it is the link for people who are searching the same thing -> [Adding Overlays to Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#AddingOverlays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics) allows you to do that [google-maps-api-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3) tag